# Websocket error: ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, websocket, telnet

So I have set up a **websocket** server with PHP, Ratchet.
I have did few tests with **telnet** and **ncat** and they **worked** fine.

But, when I try to connect to the server with **javascript** it doesn't work.
I get that error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

(yes, IP and port is correct, and I can connect it via telnet and ncat)
What could be problem? Thanks

Comment: Neither telnet nor ncat support websockets. Therefore, your statement is really puzzling. Unless you are typing websocket data frames by hand into them, telnet and ncat will just show that the port is opened, which is the case anyway - otherwise, you'd get a different error message. Can you connect with wscat?

Comment: @phihag This is the error I get: "error: Error: Parse Error". And, on documentation, they connect with telnet o.O (http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world)

Comment: Oh. I didn't read all of the documentation.. I needed to use "new HttpServer( new WsServer( new blabla() ) )" . I was using "new blabla()". It works now!

Answer (score 3):

I was using:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8080
);
```

But, in [tutorial](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world), they are using this code to make it a Websocket

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
```

(remember to include HttpServer and WsServer libs)


That fixed my problem. Sorry for not reading whole page :(